# XML output not handled correctly

Tags: xml

This is some xml that's getting outputted on a webpage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
    <page>1</page>
    <total>1</total>
    <records>4</records>
    <row id="">
        <cell>32</cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[<a href="..//classes/forms_dispatcher.php?formdef=pages&id=32&s_action=edit" target="_self" class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil ui-gi'>
        </a>
        <a onclick="delete_confirm('..//classes/forms_dispatcher.php?s_action=delete&formdef=pages&id=32')" class='ui-icon ui-icon-close ui-gi'>
    </a>
</span>]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[32]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[test]]></cell>
    </row>
    <row id="">
        <cell>31</cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[<a href="..//classes/forms_dispatcher.php?formdef=pages&id=31&s_action=edit" target="_self" class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil ui-gi'>
    </a>
    <a onclick="delete_confirm('..//classes/forms_dispatcher.php?s_action=delete&formdef=pages&id=31')" class='ui-icon ui-icon-close ui-gi'>
</a>
</span>]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[31]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[Open to Everyone]]></cell>
    </row>
    <row id="">
        <cell>10</cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[<a href="..//classes/forms_dispatcher.php?formdef=pages&id=10&s_action=edit" target="_self" class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil ui-gi'>
    </a>
    <a onclick="delete_confirm('..//classes/forms_dispatcher.php?s_action=delete&formdef=pages&id=10')" class='ui-icon ui-icon-close ui-gi'>
</a>
</span>]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[10]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[Open to Authenticated Users]]></cell>
    </row>
    <row id="">
        <cell>6</cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[<a href="..//classes/forms_dispatcher.php?formdef=pages&id=6&s_action=edit" target="_self" class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil ui-gi'>
    </a>
    <a onclick="delete_confirm('..//classes/forms_dispatcher.php?s_action=delete&formdef=pages&id=6')" class='ui-icon ui-icon-close ui-gi'>
</a>
</span>]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[6]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[General Administration]]></cell>
    </row>
</rows>
```

That's the entire source of the page.
For some reason it's getting formatted like:

1 1 4 32 ]]> 31 ]]> 10 ]]> 6 ]]>

It seems to be trying to parse the xml as html which is messing things up.  I have the same code running on a different server, outputting basically the same XML and the browser recognizes it as XML.  Is there a server setting for this?  Am I missing something obvious?

Update:
Similar XML file being rendered in a browser:
[image: Recognizes XML]

This XML file being rendered in the same browser:

[image: Tries as HTML]

Something is different, and I don't know what.

Comment: That's not a webpage, that an XML file. Any browser that sees this will try to display whatever it can recognize, typically the text inside an element. You are probably missing the XSLT transformation that will convert this XML file to an HTML page

Comment: How would you like the browser to display your XML?

Comment: I realize it's an XML file, but the browser picks it up and renders appropriately, but doesn't for this one.  I added images

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to the media type (aka MIME type or content type) in the HTTP headers. These affect the way in which the browser attempts to render the file. The server is probably configured to set the MIME type based on the file extension of the file being requested.

Answer (score 0):

It would only show up in firebug, but one of my PHP files had some BOM marks at the beginning which was messing up the XML

[image]